# A valid Sudoku Generator without backtracking in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion, sudoku

I am new to programming. I tried to write a valid Sudoku *solver* with backtracking, the performance is disappointing.

So, I tried to generate a valid Sudoku generator without backtracking.

The white paper implementation is 1/3 of the required numbers of strategy to generate valid Sudoku without problem. The other 2/3 is still not published because it is still in theory.

I spent 4 days to refactor the code, do you think the code is worth of 4 days?

Feel free to recommend me something to read, or how to make my code more maintainable.

The github repository: https://github.com/kidfrom/sudoku_js

The white paper: https://github.com/kidfrom/sudoku_js/blob/master/dump/white_paper.MD

The code: https://github.com/kidfrom/sudoku_js/blob/master/assets/js/generateSudoku.js

````
let subGridRowLength;
let subGridLength;
let gridRowLength;
let gridLength;

function newGrid(value) {
  // reset global variables
  gridNestedArray = [];
  statusNestedArray = [];

  // global variables;
  subGridRowLength = value;
  subGridLength = Math.pow(subGridRowLength, 2);
  gridRowLength = Math.pow(subGridRowLength, 2);
  gridLength = Math.pow(subGridRowLength, 4);

  let gridFlatArray = [];
  let statusFlatArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < gridLength; i++) {
    gridFlatArray.push(0);
    statusFlatArray.push(undefined);
  }

  return flatToNestedArray(gridFlatArray, statusFlatArray);
}

let gridNestedArray = [];
let statusNestedArray = []; // true = sorted, false = not sorted yet.

function flatToNestedArray(gridFlatArray, statusFlatArray) {
  let i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < gridLength; i += gridRowLength) {
    let tempGridRow = gridFlatArray.slice(i, i + gridRowLength);
    gridNestedArray.push(tempGridRow);

    let tempStatusRow = statusFlatArray.slice(i, i + gridRowLength);
    statusNestedArray.push(tempStatusRow);
  }

  return populateTheNestedArray();
}

function populateTheNestedArray() {
  // r0, c0 is relative to the Grid. r0, c0 is the NestedArray[0][0] of each subGrid.
  // rSG, cSG is relative to the subGrid.
  for (let r0 = 0; r0 < gridRowLength; r0 += subGridRowLength) {
    for (let c0 = 0; c0 < gridRowLength; c0 += subGridRowLength) {
      let numbers = possibleNumbers();
      for (let rSG = 0; rSG < subGridRowLength; rSG++) {
        for (let cSG = 0; cSG < subGridRowLength; cSG++) {
          n = Math.floor(Math.random() * gridRowLength + 1); // random 1 to 9
          if (numbers.indexOf(n) > -1) {
            numbers.splice(numbers.indexOf(n), 1); // prevent double numbers within the subGrid.
            gridNestedArray[r0 + rSG][c0 + cSG] = n;
          } else cSG--; // loop until random generated n = numbers.
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // debug only: ERROR steps 2 vertical needs new strategy || Fixed
  // subGridRowLength = 2;
  // gridNestedArray = [
  //   [3, 2, 1, 2],
  //   [1, 4, 4, 3],
  //   [2, 3, 1, 3],
  //   [1, 4, 4, 2]
  // ];

  // debug only: ERROR steps 3 horizontal needs new strategy || Fixed
  // subGridRowLength = 2;
  // gridNestedArray = [
  //   [1, 4, 3, 2],
  //   [2, 3, 1, 4],
  //   [4, 2, 4, 3],
  //   [3, 1, 2, 1]
  // ];

  // debug only: ERROR horizontal steps 3 needs new strategy || Fixed
  // subGridRowLength = 2;
  // gridNestedArray = [
  //   [3,4,3,2],
  //   [1,2,1,4],
  //   [4,2,3,2],
  //   [3,1,1,4]
  // ];

  // debug only: ERROR vertical steps 8 needs new strategy || Fixed
  // debug only: ERROR horizontal steps 7 needs new strategy -> bug occured again after adjustment to follow the Swap, Sort, Shrink strategy.
  // subGridRowLength = 3;
  // gridNestedArray = [
  //     [5, 8, 3, 1, 9, 6, 7, 2, 8],
  //     [9, 7, 6, 2, 4, 5, 4, 3, 1],
  //     [1, 4, 2, 3, 8, 7, 5, 6, 9],
  //     [7, 2, 4, 6, 3, 1, 5, 9, 7],
  //     [8, 9, 1, 5, 2, 8, 6, 4, 3],
  //     [6, 3, 5, 4, 7, 9, 2, 1, 8],
  //     [2, 1, 8, 7, 5, 2, 6, 9, 5],
  //     [3, 6, 7, 9, 1, 4, 8, 3, 4],
  //     [4, 5, 9, 8, 6, 3, 1, 7, 2]
  // ];

  // debug only: ERROR vertical steps 2 needs new strategy
  // subGridRowLength = 2;
  // gridNestedArray = [
  //   [3, 2, 3, 1],
  //   [4, 1, 2, 4],
  //   [3, 4, 3, 1],
  //   [1, 2, 2, 4]
  // ];
  
  // debug only: ERROR vertical steps 1 needs new strategy
  // subGridRowlength = 2;
  // gridNestedArray = [
  //     [8,4,5,4,6,3,1,6,9],
  //     [3,1,2,9,8,7,4,8,3],
  //     [9,6,7,1,5,2,5,2,7],
  //     [2,3,4,6,7,3,1,9,8],
  //     [8,1,6,9,4,5,2,5,4],
  //     [7,5,9,8,1,2,7,3,6],
  //     [2,9,5,4,9,8,3,2,8],
  //     [7,1,3,3,1,7,4,6,5],
  //     [6,4,8,5,6,2,9,7,1]
  // ];

  // debug only: ERROR horizontal steps 4 needs new strategy
  // subGridRowLength = 3;
  // gridNestedArray = [
  //   [4,6,7,5,3,8,9,3,8],
  //   [3,8,9,6,9,1,1,6,5],
  //   [2,5,1,2,7,4,2,7,4],
  //   [9,2,3,6,9,1,9,8,4],
  //   [8,1,4,2,8,4,7,3,5],
  //   [6,5,7,5,7,3,6,2,1],
  //   [5,6,9,2,6,9,5,2,3],
  //   [8,7,3,5,7,8,8,7,6],
  //   [4,1,2,4,3,1,1,9,4]
  // ];

  // debug only
  console.log(`=== Start: Before Fix ===`)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(gridNestedArray));
  console.log(`=== End ===`)

  return loopsteps();
}

function possibleNumbers() {
  let numbers = [];
  for (let n = 1; n <= gridRowLength; n++) {
    numbers.push(n);
  }
  return numbers;
}

function loopsteps() {
  // horizontal steps 0 -> veritcal steps 0 -> horizontal steps 1 -> repeat
  for (let steps = 0; steps < gridRowLength; steps++) {
    if (check("horizontal", steps, "canFix") === false) {
      console.log(`ERROR horizontal steps ${steps} needs new strategy`);
      break;
    }

    if (check("vertical", steps, "canFix") === false) {
      console.log(`ERROR vertical steps ${steps} needs new strategy`);
      break;
    }
  }
}

function check(turns, steps, request) {
  if (isValid(turns, steps) === true) {
    updateStatus(turns, steps);
  } else if (isValid(turns, steps) === false) {
    // TODO: add new strategy

    // swap unsorted with unsorted
    if (sortWithSG(turns, steps, "canSort") === true) {
      sortWithSG(turns, steps, "sort");
      check(turns, steps); // recursive
    }

    // swap the nextLastIndexOf duplicate.
    else if (sortWithSG(turns, steps, "canSort", true) === true) {
      sortWithSG(turns, steps, "sort", true);
      check(turns, steps); // recursive
    }

    else if (request === "canFix") return false;
  }
}

function isValid(turns, steps) {
  let tempFlatArray = [];

  // horizontal
  if (turns === "horizontal") {
    tempFlatArray = gridNestedArray[steps];
  }
  
  // vertical
  else if (turns === "vertical") {
    tempFlatArray = columnToFlatArray(steps);
  }
  
  // ERROR
  else { 
    console.log(`ERROR isValid(${turns}) the turns' parameter is not found`);
    return;
  }

  if (new Set(tempFlatArray).size !== tempFlatArray.length) {
    return false; // isValid false
  }

  // check passed: isValid true
  if (turns === "horizontal" || turns === "vertical") return true;
}

function columnToFlatArray(steps) {
  let tempFlatArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < gridRowLength; i++) tempFlatArray.push(gridNestedArray[i][steps]);
  return tempFlatArray;
}

function updateStatus(turns, steps) {
  for (let i = gridRowLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // horizontal
    if (turns === "horizontal" && typeof statusNestedArray[steps][i] === 'undefined') {
      statusNestedArray[steps][i] = steps;
    }

    // vertical
    else if (turns === "vertical" && typeof statusNestedArray[i][steps] === 'undefined') {
      statusNestedArray[i][steps] = steps;
    }
  }
}

function sortWithSG(turns, steps, request, next) {
  let index;

  if (typeof next === 'undefined') {
    index = listDuplicates(turns, steps, "lastIndexOf");
  }
  
  // nextLastIndexOf
  else if (next === true) {
    index = listDuplicates(turns, steps, "nextLastIndexOf");
  }

  let tempSubGrid = [];

  let tempFlatArray = [];

  if (turns === "horizontal") {
    tempFlatArray = gridNestedArray[steps];
    if (typeof statusNestedArray[steps][index] === 'undefined') {
      tempSubGrid = subGrid(turns, steps, index);
    } else if (typeof statusNestedArray[steps][index] != 'undefined') {
      tempSubGrid = subGrid("vertical", index, steps); // inverted
    }
  } else if (turns === "vertical") {
    tempFlatArray = columnToFlatArray(steps);
    if (typeof statusNestedArray[index][steps] === 'undefined') {
      tempSubGrid = subGrid(turns, steps, index);
    } else if (typeof statusNestedArray[index][steps] != 'undefined') {
      tempSubGrid = subGrid("horizontal", index, steps); // inverted
    }
  }

  // debug only
  if (turns === "horizontal") {
    console.log(`${turns} steps ${steps} index ${index}
      sort status ${statusNestedArray[steps][index]}
      tempFlatArray ${tempFlatArray}
      tempSubGrid ${tempSubGrid}`
    );
  } else if (turns === "vertical") {
    console.log(`${turns} index ${index} steps ${steps}
      sort status ${statusNestedArray[index][steps]}
      tempFlatArray ${tempFlatArray}
      tempSubGrid ${tempSubGrid}`
    );
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < tempSubGrid.length; i++) {
    if (typeof tempSubGrid[i] === 'undefined' || 
        tempFlatArray.indexOf(tempSubGrid[i]) > -1
    ) continue;

    if (tempFlatArray.indexOf(tempSubGrid[i]) === -1) {
      // request: canSort
      if (request === "canSort") {
        return true;
      }

      // request: sort
      else if (request === "sort") {
        let rSG = Math.floor(
          Math.floor(i / subGridRowLength)
        );
        let cSG = i % subGridRowLength;
  
        // horizontal
        if (turns === "horizontal") {
          let r0 = Math.floor(
            Math.floor(steps / subGridRowLength) * subGridRowLength
          );
          let c0 = Math.floor(
            Math.floor(index / subGridRowLength) * subGridRowLength
          );
          gridNestedArray[steps][index] = [
            gridNestedArray[r0 + rSG][c0 + cSG],
            gridNestedArray[r0 + rSG][c0 + cSG] = gridNestedArray[steps][index]
          ][0];
        }
        
        // vertical
        else if (turns === "vertical") {
          let r0 = Math.floor(
            Math.floor(index / subGridRowLength) * subGridRowLength
          );
          let c0 = Math.floor(
            Math.floor(steps / subGridRowLength) * subGridRowLength
          );
          gridNestedArray[index][steps] = [
            gridNestedArray[r0 + rSG][c0 + cSG],
            gridNestedArray[r0 + rSG][c0 + cSG] = gridNestedArray[index][steps]
          ][0];
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}

function listDuplicates(turns, steps, request, index) {
  let tempFlatArray = [];

  // horizontal
  if (turns === "horizontal") {
    tempFlatArray = gridNestedArray[steps];
  }

  // vertical
  else if (turns === "vertical") {
    tempFlatArray = columnToFlatArray(steps);
  }

  else {
    console.log(`ERROR listDuplicates(${turns}, steps, request) turns' parameter is not found`);
    return;
  }

  // request: lastIndexOf
  if (request === "lastIndexOf") {
    let tempDuplicates = listDuplicates(turns, steps, "list");
    return tempFlatArray.lastIndexOf(
      tempDuplicates[tempDuplicates.length - 1]
    ); // index
  }
  
  // request: nextLastIndexOf
  if (request === "nextLastIndexOf") {
    let tempDuplicates = listDuplicates(turns, steps, "list");
    return tempFlatArray.lastIndexOf(
      tempDuplicates[tempDuplicates.length - 1],
      tempFlatArray.lastIndexOf(
        tempDuplicates[tempDuplicates.length - 1]
      ) - 1
    ); // index
  }

  // request: list
  else if (request === "list") {
    return tempFlatArray.filter(
      (item, index) => tempFlatArray.indexOf(item) != index
    ); // list
  }

  else console.log(`ERROR listDuplicates(turns, steps, ${request}) request' parameter is not found`);
}

function subGrid(turns, steps, index) {
  let tempSubGrid = [];

  // r0, c0 is relative to the Grid. r0, c0 is the 0,0 of each subGrid.
  let r0;
  let c0;

  // horizontal
  if (turns === "horizontal") {
    r0 = Math.floor(
      Math.floor(steps / subGridRowLength) * subGridRowLength
    );
    c0 = Math.floor(
      Math.floor(index / subGridRowLength) * subGridRowLength
    );
  }

  else if (turns === "vertical") {
    r0 = Math.floor(
      Math.floor(index / subGridRowLength) * subGridRowLength
    );
    c0 = Math.floor(
      Math.floor(steps / subGridRowLength) * subGridRowLength
    );
  }

  // rSG, cSG is relative to the subGrid.
  for (let rSG = 0; rSG < subGridRowLength; rSG++) {
    for (let cSG = 0; cSG < subGridRowLength; cSG++) {
      // horizontal
      if (turns === "horizontal") {
        // if sorted
        if (typeof statusNestedArray[steps][index] != 'undefined') {
          // cSG > index % subGridRowLength; is to prevent accidentally resorting sorted row.
          if (statusNestedArray[r0 + rSG][c0 + cSG] === steps && cSG > index % subGridRowLength) tempSubGrid.push(gridNestedArray[r0 + rSG][c0 + cSG]);
          else tempSubGrid.push(undefined);
        }

        // if not sorted
        else if (typeof statusNestedArray[steps][index] === 'undefined') {
          if (rSG === 0 || typeof statusNestedArray[r0 + rSG][c0 + cSG] != 'undefined') {
            tempSubGrid.push(undefined);
            continue; // prevent overlapping with the next if statement.
          }
          tempSubGrid.push(gridNestedArray[r0 + rSG][c0 + cSG]);
        }
      }

      // vertical
      else if (turns === "vertical") {
        // if sorted
        if (typeof statusNestedArray[index][steps] != 'undefined'){
          // rSG > index % subGridRowLength; is to prevent accidentally resorting sorted the column.
          if (statusNestedArray[r0 + rSG][c0 + cSG] === steps && rSG > index % subGridRowLength) tempSubGrid.push(gridNestedArray[r0 + rSG][c0 + cSG]);
          else tempSubGrid.push(undefined);
        }
        
        // if not sorted
        else if (typeof statusNestedArray[index][steps] === 'undefined') {
          if (cSG === 0 || typeof statusNestedArray[r0 + rSG][c0 + cSG] != 'undefined') {
            tempSubGrid.push(undefined);
            continue; // prevent overlapping with the next if statement.
          }
          tempSubGrid.push(gridNestedArray[r0 + rSG][c0 + cSG]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return tempSubGrid;
}
```
````

Comment: Hi, I have removed the backtracking tag from the question. Although you mention you had implementation using backtracking, that version is not posted here and so the tag seemed inappropriate.

Comment: @slepic I appreciate it. Thank you.